# Is below mathematical rigorous and the simplest way to find $x$ for the imaginary unit $i$ such that $i^n=x$?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$ i^n= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{for $4|n$} \\
i & \text{for $4|(n-1)$} \\
-1 & \text{for $4|(n-2)$} \\
-i & \text{for $4|(n-3)$} \\
\end{cases} ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

(Came up with this, because I could not find anything simpler, most sources suggest to just break down the power $n$ to the closest multiple of $4$ , giving $1$, and then multiply the remainder of the exponent to find $x$. Does not seem very efficient)

Comment: Use congruences modulo $4$ for the exponent.

Comment: @heptapod If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: by remainder theorem we have $$n=4k+r,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;r\in\{0,1,2,3\}$$

So $$i^n = (i^4)^n\cdot i^r = 1\cdot i^r =...$$

Answer (score 1):

If **n=2m is even** you can consider:

$$i^n=-1 \cdot i^m$$

If **n is odd** I don't see any other way to simplify the calculation.